# Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 32-bit with Node.js 4.x

Tags: node.js

I am running a `npm run build` and get the following error

```
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 32-bit with Node.js 4.x

 Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 6.x
```

So i am doing `npm rebuild node-sass` and it gave the error

```
> node-sass@3.10.1 install /root/PokemonGo-Map/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/root/PokemonGo-Map/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

Any one can tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Maybe the sass compiler is missing. You need to hace ruby and run this command: `gem install sass`

Comment: still the same error